# codeigniter multiple search function

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to develop a search function in php using codeigniter framework. It should be able to search using the time and the hall too. it works when i use only the time.But it gets very wrong when i use hall.following i have attached all the codes i am using.

I have divided Model into two sections like model and service. in the model there are getters and setters.In the service class only i am writing querys.if anyone can give me a positive answer that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

**Model(reservation_service.php)**

```php
function search_reservations($time,$hall) {
    $this->db->select('reservations.*');
    $this->db->from('reservations');        
    $this->db->like('time', $time);
    $this->db->or_like('hall',$hall);
    $this->db->where('is_deleted', '0');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller(dashboard.php)**

```php
function search_results() {
    $reservation_service = new Reservation_service();
    $time_booking = trim($this->input->post('time', TRUE));
    $hall_booking = trim($this->input->post('hall', TRUE));
    $data['search_results'] = $reservation_service->search_reservations($time_booking,$hall_booking);
    $partials = array('content' => 'dashboard/search_results');
    $this->template->load('template/main_template', $partials, $data);
}

function search_reservations() {
    $reservation_service = new Reservation_service();
    $data['search_results'] = $reservation_service->search_reservations(trim($this->input->post('time', TRUE)));
    $partials = array('content' => 'dashboard/reservation_report');
    $this->template->load('template/main_template', $partials, $data);
}
```

**view**

reservation_report.php

```php
<div class="form-group"><br>
    <input id="time"  name="time" type="text" placeholder="Time Slot">
    <input id="hall"  name="hall" type="text" placeholder="Hall">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="search()" >Search</button>
</div>
<div id="search_results">
    <?php echo $this->load->view('dashboard/search_results'); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search() {
        var time = $('#time').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/dashboard/search_results',
            data: "time=" + time,
            success: function(msg) {

                $('#search_results').html(msg);

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

search_results.php

```php
<div class="adv-table">                    
    <table  class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id="bookings_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Hall</th>
                <th>Time</th>                      
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($search_results as $result) {
                ?>
                <tr id="bookings_<?php echo $result->id; ?>">
                    <td><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result->date; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result->hall; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result->time; ?></td>   
                <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem, Please be specific.

Comment: which codeigniter version are you using ? use once  or_where instead of or_like.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with ajax function here you are not sending the value of `hall variable` in post

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search() {
        var time = $('#time').val();
        var hall = $('#hall').val();// add this to your code

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/dashboard/search_results',
            data: {time:time,hall:hall},//pass parameter 
            success: function(msg) {

                $('#search_results').html(msg);

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be wrong when loading model in `dashboard.php`:

```
$reservation_service = new Reservation_service();
```

Try to load your model object as described in [CodeIgniter Documentations](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model):

```
$this->load->model('reservation_service');
```

therefore your **dashboard.php** should be like this:

```
function search_results() {
    $this->load->model('reservation_service');
    $time_booking = trim($this->input->post('time', TRUE));
    $hall_booking = trim($this->input->post('hall', TRUE));
    $data['search_results'] = $this->reservation_service->search_reservations($time_booking,$hall_booking);
    $partials = array('content' => 'dashboard/search_results');
    $this->template->load('template/main_template', $partials, $data);
}

function search_reservations() {
    $this->load->model('reservation_service');
    $data['search_results'] = $this->reservation_service->search_reservations(trim($this->input->post('time', TRUE)));
    $partials = array('content' => 'dashboard/reservation_report');
    $this->template->load('template/main_template', $partials, $data);
}
```

Comment: @IshaniPathinayake My pleasure, I hope so.